# spring-boot tomcat redeploy permgen leak due to logging

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, log4j, log4j2

Ran into a memory leak issue with redeploying a `spring boot 2.5` application on `tomcat 9`.

Debugging process:

1. Tomcat startup.bat
2. Deploy war
3. Reload/undeploy war
4. Run tomcat find leaks
5. Check loaded classes in visual vm

Tomcat findleaks reports a leak and visual VM indicates that the classes aren't unloaded.

Next steps:

1. Take a heapdump
2. Load dump in Eclipse Memory Analyzer
3. List objexts with incoming references and filter to **org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader**

This also lists classloaders with a `DESTROYED` state. For a destroyed classloader do the following:

1. Path to GC roots > Excluce all phantom/weak/soft/etc references

This indicates there may still be a strong reference relating to org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.StatusLoggerAdminMBean

[image: eclipse memory analyzer]

Attempted to recreate the issue in a simple spring boot project using the logback logging and log4j2. Both show the same scenario but with a different cause (shutdown hooks).

Debugging and code based on the spring boot starter can be found here: https://github.com/webbres/spring-boot-permgen-issue/tree/master/debugging

At this stage I'm unsure if the permgen leak in my actual application is related to the one in the linked repo.

Are there additional steps that need to be taken that the spring boot starter isn't handling w.r.t to using the logging frameworks in a war? I have tried adding org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-web as a dependency but this doesn't appear to resolve the shutdown hook issue in the demo project.

Feels like I'm missing something...

Adding `-Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true` to the CATALINA_OPTS and `logging.register-shutdown-hook=false` to the `application.properties` I no longer get and references when filtering out phatom/weak/soft/etc references however I do still see the DESTROYED instance of the `ParallelWebappClassLoader` and the classes aren't being unloaded

Comment: You can set `logging.register-shutdown-hook=false` to disable registration of the logging system's shutdown hook. Perhaps that will help.

Comment: Run the server with `-Dlog4j2.debug=true` and check the standard output (`catalina.out` or similar) after you stop your application. All previously registered MBeans should be unregistered.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson thank you for that pointer. Setting that property results in no strong references being found in Eclipse Memory Analyzer but the classloader still isn't being GCd and the permgen leak persists

@PiotrP.Karwasz Thank you, I have added that setting to my CATALINA_OPTS but I'm not seeing any relevant log output when I stop the application. I also tried adding ` -Dlog4j2.disable.jmx=true` which now results in no JMX bean references showing in Eclipse Memory Analyzer filter. I'm not in the same new position as with my spring boot starter demo, permgen leak but no identifier refs